# S3 into Snowflake : COPY INTO With purge = true is not deleting files in S3 Bucket

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can't find much documentation on why I'm seeing this issue. I believe I have the permissions to delete objects in S3, as I can go into the bucket on AWS and delete files myself. However, when I'm running the code below, it'll load into the staging table successfully but then I'll still see all of the files in the S3 bucket.

Is this a permission issue or is there something wrong with the way I'm creating the stage or copy statement?

```
create or replace stage s3_stage 
    url='s3://bucket_name/folder/'
    credentials = (
        aws_key_id= 'my_key_id'
        aws_secret_key='my_secret_key')
    file_format = (type = 'parquet');

copy into staging_table
    from (
        select 
        $1:id,
        COALESCE($1:Op, 'F'),
        $1:timestamp,
        $1
        from @s3_stage)
    pattern = ".*folder/.*"
    file_format = (type = 'parquet')
    purge = TRUE;
```

Comment: I found this in the Snowflake documentation about the PURGE option: "If this option is set to TRUE, note that a best effort is made to remove successfully loaded data files. If the purge operation fails for any reason, no error is returned currently. We recommend that you list staged files periodically (using LIST) and manually remove successfully loaded files, if any exist."

If it's consistent behavior, maybe you could additionally try setting the PURGE option in the stage or in the stage_copy_options for the table?    I am curious if this occurs for all your tables.

Comment: A couple of thoughts... (1) Are you sure that the user running this copy statement has the required AWS permissions to delete from S3? (2) This is pure conjecture on my part as there is nothing in the documentation to support this, but as you are doing a SELECT rather than just a straight COPY, maybe this doesn't delete the records as you haven't, in theory, read all parts of all of the records and you could be copying other parts of the records to other tables in subsequent COPY statements. Just a thought

Comment: @SuzyLockwood yeah I did see that as well - but it's consistent behaviour across any table I create. I tried both ways- with the stage_copy_options set AND doing it through the copy into command. Both are producing the same results.

Comment: @NickW for (1) I followed the S3 setup docs in Snowflake just to make sure, and even that didn't work. I do have a DeleteObject permission (Full Access to S3) - and I can go into the bucket and delete a bunch of files. Unless that's a false indication of proper permissions?? Not sure (2) Maybe I'll try this one out to see what happens.

Comment: @Ashley  It should purge the files used in the COPY operation.  The pattern should work, but maybe you could test with just loading a specific file as well from a stage, even a simple CSV with no transformative statements.   

If it still doesn't work, then it strikes me as S3 permissions.  Check that you have all the permissions and setup done here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html#step-1-configure-access-permissions-for-the-s3-bucket

Comment: @SuzyLockwood yeah I tried without the transformative statements and same thing! So I was leaning towards permissions as well. It was in fact permissions issue - I wasn't specifying access to the folders inside the bucket in one section of the policy. FACEPALM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ashley Ah, glad to hear you figured it out.  Thanks for sharing the solution!